# Was this scene ever filmed in Police Academy (1984) or am I just imagining it?

Tags: alternate-version, police-academy

I would have been 10 years old when I first saw it in a theater. In it, Lt. Harris (GW Bailey) is stuck in a traffic jam and commandeers a moped or motorbike and tries to speed through traffic. Someone opens a door to block his path, and he is launched into the air towards a horse trailer. Mahoney (Gutenberg) makes a one-liner joke insinuating that Harris's head has penetrated the rectum of the horse.

That portion still exists in every version of the movie (save maybe some 1980s network television edits for FCC obscenity reasons).

However, I also remember a 1-to-2 second shot of an actual depiction of this. I would expect that some simple animatronic sculptures were used for it (as movies tended to use in the 1980s), supposing of course I didn't just imagine it in my perverted 10 yr old mind.

It's not difficult to imagine why it might have been removed from later videotape and DVD copies, though it's a bit hard to reconcile this even with an R rating.

In general, do some scenes in movies disappear, so much that no evidence can be found on the internet that they ever existed, and in particular is there any evidence that such a scene as this existed and was then purged?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed such tweaks are commonly made to movies.  I distinctly remember Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio's bare breasts in [*The Abyss*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096754/) during the CPR scene of the original theatrical release.  No doubt that was eliminated from every version since because they greatly distracted from the seriousness of the situation—her breasts were very attractive, but the shot was about her probably being dead.  Possibly that edit would not have occurred for a European edition.

In one of the DVD re-releases of [*Star Wars IV*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/), the commentary by George Lucas has him remark to one of the DVD release crew that Lucas adjusted some special effect in the movie the day before and was surprised to see it on the DVD master already.  This was a very minor change, but the accumulation of tweaks from 1977 to 1990-something presented a very different looking Mos Isley:  the city was a tiny desert oasis in 1977, but by 1995 it had become a bustling medium-sized city.

In [*Nothing in Common*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091653/), Jackie Gleason's character's line "go to hell" to his wife trying to support him at the hospital was present in the original theatrical release, but disappeared from every subsequent edition.  It is only a 1.5 second difference, but its absence greatly alters his character toward a more ambiguous one, potentially worthy of sympathy.  I really resented the movie when the line was there.

The scene described in *Police Academy* seems like it is so disgusting, the director or producer might have decided to drop it to avoid alienating the majority of the intended audience.  Perhaps a special DVD edition ("disgusting edit"?) would allow viewing it.

Comment: The Abyss scene was not cut in the DVD version... at least not in the version I have.

Comment: @legomaker:  Do you recall the length of time they were onscreen?  I think the original threatrical version had 20+ seconds of them.

Comment: By 'they' I assume you are referring to her breasts. Yes, they did appear for quite a significant time in the scene. I recall because, other than the obvious reasons, I did not remember seeing them when I watched the movie for the first time. I have a special edition version of the DVD.

Answer (score -2):

The scene exists fella and I remember it as well.
I didn't even realise they'd started removing it but I have noticed a few movies doing this type of thing of late. In an ideal world the studios want as many people to see a movie as possible so the lower the rating that better. This could potentially have compromised.

The scene is out there... You can watch it here..
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pobCoKFEfXk

"Someone call a veterinarian!"

Comment: That scene does not show what the OP is asking about. He is saying there was a 1-2 second scene of the head actually in the horse.

Comment: My bad I'd misunderstood the question. I'd be super surprised if there ever was a scene that shows it so graphically. I certainly can't remember it like that and I was an 80s child interested in slapstick humour. Anyone with the VHS may offer help.

Comment: @JohnP I'm not sure the scene exists... now that I know what I do about MPAA ratings and all that, it's just absurd to think that it could ever have made it through with only an R. But I do remember it, so I'm trying to figure out if I really do remember it or only think that I do.

Comment: @JamesDrayson - I have no evidence either way, but it is entirely possible it existed and the "vulgarity" of it could have easily been hidden by the horse's tail.   All you really need is a shot of someone's shoulders and a tail flapping between their shoulderblades, and your mind would fill in the blanks.